# OpenSSL 1.1.1d - Async use of SSL_CTX_set_cert_verify_callback?

Tags: c++, ssl, openssl, certificate, ssl-certificate

Certificate validation in general requires asynchronous operations such as: OCSP/CRL fetch.

On the other hand, the callback from `SSL_CTX_set_cert_verify_callback` expects a synchronous result:
1 (success) / 0 (failure). ([reference](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man3/SSL_CTX_set_cert_verify_callback.html)).

I find it kind of odd that any validation of this type is expected to be synchronous.

Is there an alternative API for certificate chain validation that supports asynchronous operations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In theory I think you should be able to use the OpenSSL ASYNC API to do this. Normally this is used by asynchronous capable engines, but I don't see why it wouldn't also work in applications.

Firstly you would need to put your SSL object into ASYNC mode using the function call `SSL_set_mode()` and specifying `SSL_MODE_ASYNC`. You can also do this at the SSL_CTX level using `SSL_CTX_set_mode()`. See:

https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man3/SSL_set_mode.html

Once that is done you need to ensure your application is prepared to handle the return value `SSL_ERROR_WANT_ASYNC` from any call to `SSL_get_error()`. See:

https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man3/SSL_get_error.html

Your application can then implement a callback in the normal way via `SSL_CTX_set_cert_verify_callback`. If it needs to temporarily pause operation to wait for some asynchronous operation to complete then the callback should call `ASYNC_pause_job()`. See:

https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man3/ASYNC_pause_job.html

This will have the effect of control returning to your main application and `SSL_get_error()` will return `SSL_ERROR_WANT_ASYNC`. You will need to implement some mechanism for your application to know when asynchronous processing is complete. When it is, then simply retry the SSL I/O call that was previously paused. Note: this *must* occur on the same thread that the original call was made from. Your callback will then resume from the point at which it previously paused.

Comment: Great idea, I'll give it a try and update if it's indeed possible. But I have two questions beforehand: 
1) How can I call the ASYNC_pause_job() method from the certificate verify callback? It expects an answer in any case. Or perhaps you're suggesting to call the ASYNC_pause_job() from different context before the callback is even called?
2) What's the importance of SSL_get_error() exactly?

Comment: The ASYNC API works by creating a completely separate stack for code operating asynchronously. When you call ASYNC_pause_job() execution of your callback is literally paused at that point in its execution and the state of the stack saved away. The flow of control immediately returns to your application. When you re-call the SSL I/O call then your callback is resumed exactly where it left off with its stack in exactly the same state - as if nothing had happened. So the callback only returns when the async operation it is waiting for has actually finished.

Comment: SSL_get_error() is a fundamental function call for writing libssl applications. If you call a libssl I/O functions such as SSL_read()/SSL_write()/SSL_connect()/SSL_accept() etc you need to check whether the operation was successful or not. If the call returns an error code then you must call SSL_get_error() to determine what to do next. The error might be temporary (e.g. data isn't currently available to read - but you can try again later), or it might be permanent (e.g. some fatal error such as the underlying socket being closed). SSL_get_error() tells you what type of error you have got.

Comment: But as far as I understand the ASYNC_pause_job() works when inside a job context, correct? Meaning that the certificate verify callback itself should be executed using ASYNC_start_job() internally from OpenSSL, which doesn't happen by default. (unless I manually change it)

Comment: If you set SSL_MODE_ASYNC then all libssl IO operations occur inside a job, so it should be perfectly ok to call ASYNC_pause_job() inside the callback.

Comment: @MattCaswell, how do you "notify" openssl that the callback (which called `ASYNC_pause_job()`) can resume?   I expected there are some fds in ASYNC_WAIT_CTX on which openssl select()s but it's empty (`ASYNC_WAIT_CTX_get_all_fds(ASYNC_get_wait_ctx(ASYNC_get_current_job()), nullptr, &n); n == 0`)?

Comment: @demeter that is probably a whole separate question in itself....not something I can fully answer in a comment. Briefly though you don't need to notify OpenSSL at all. Your async certificate callback needs to notify the application that it should resume the SSL connection. It can do this through the ASYNC_WAIT_CTX fds. The async certificate callback needs to set the fd in the ASYNC_WAIT_CTX using ASYNC_WAIT_CTX_set_wait_fd() and mark it readable when it is time to resume. See https://www.openssl.org/docs/man3.0/man3/ASYNC_WAIT_CTX_get_fd.html.

Comment: Note that now that OpenSSL 3.0 has been released there is a better way to do this than the approach in my answer above - at least on the client side. The cert verify callback set via SSL_CTX_set_cert_verify_callback() can now support asynchronous verification directly. The callback can return -1 to indicate that a retry is required. See https://www.openssl.org/docs/man3.0/man3/SSL_CTX_set_cert_verify_callback.html